# Eclipse Android Virtual Device Manager doesn't launch

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse 4.2.1 (Juno).

My Android Virtual Device Manager does not launch. I press on the button and literally nothing happens (no error message).

I've tried reinstalling the Android SDK, ADT and Eclipse but nothing helps to fix this issue.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same problem when relocating my entire developement directory.  Deleting the folder and relaunching Eclipse resolved it.

Comment: What is the original path to that folder?

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem. After several reinstalls, restarts and what not, I finally figured it out:
 
open cmd, run `android avd` from `sdk\tools` folder. You'll probably get an exception that you can google, which is already better than no response at all...
This is what I got:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdInfo.getDeviceName(AvdInfo.java:158)
```

What did the trick for me was deleting the folder `C:\Users\<User>\.android\avd`.

Comment: I saved a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

In this case reinstalling will help
get the android development package from developers site.....

and you can try by running in a new User Account in your PC
some times it workss!!!
all the best!

- Close Eclipse

  - Kill adb through command line with command adb kill-server
  - Now start task manager and kill adb process also from there if running from the process tab
  - Now start your adb again from command line with adb start-server
    -Now start your Eclipse again and run your application

Try!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was a problem with old */tmp/android-username/emulator-** files.
I found it out by running manually my predefined arm AVD named "Test"

```
$ cd adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130522/sdk/tools
$ ./emulator64-arm -avd Test
NAND: could not write file /tmp/android-username/emulator-gKbQ19, File exists
```

Removing old emulator files from */tmp/android-username* resolved the problem.

```
rm /tmp/android-username/emulator-*
```